# where to find previous versions in official website

Tags: versions

i cant find how to install the .ISO file of ubuntu 16.04. it shows me only the 18.04 version. thank you.

Comment: Here you go:http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.4/

Comment: They say that on their website and refer to this link: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads. Scroll down to "past releases".

Answer (score 0):

Just check one of the offical mirror pages, you will find the ISOs there
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors